# How to Achieve this Requirement ???Can i use Jave Script , CSS and Visual force page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html

Can any one help me out , based on quote line items can we create a layout like by prepopulating items, price & qty and next 6 qtrs.
Example below 2 part numbers are  in quote line items, also default the price from quote line item.  Upon saving ,it should save as detailed record for each quarter. Creating a custom object  and calling them in Visual force page or by using JavaScript and CSS .Any suggestions plz.I shall appreciate your help.[image]

i tried previously in this way

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomLineItem__c"  sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
      <apex:commandButton value="SAVE" action="{!SAVE}"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="SAVE&MORE" action="{!SAVE}"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="CANCEL" action="{!CANCEL}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageblockSection title="Schedule"> 
     <apex:inputField value="{!CustomLineItem__c.ProductPartNumbers__c}" label="Product"/>  
     <apex:inputField value="{!CustomLineItem__c.Year__c}" label="Year"/> 
      <apex:inputField value="{!CustomLineItem__c.PricingRequestsQuarterNos__c}" label="Quarter"/> 
      <apex:inputField value="{!CustomLineItem__c.Quantity__c}"/> 
      <apex:inputField value="{!CustomLineItem__c.Price__c}"/>
   </apex:pageblockSection>
  </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: what have attempted so far?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava :I tried previously with visual force tag please find the code above.Now their changed it to above screen shot.How can i get this .Any suggestion plz